# Running action on child node not sequenced

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have animation action on child node and I want to run it in action sequence of scene. I want to call some code block only after child node actions are finished.

Here is child action:

```
func animationAction(animation: Animation) -> SKAction {
    let textures = animations[animation.rawValue]
    let action = SKAction.animateWithTextures(textures, timePerFrame: 1 / NSTimeInterval(30))
    return SKAction.runAction(action, onChildWithName: name!)
}
```

Here is sequence action running for scene and child node `hero`:

```
var actions = [SKAction]()
actions.append(hero.animationAction(Animation.Loose))
actions.append(SKAction.runBlock({ () -> Void in
    // point #1
}))
runAction(SKAction.sequence(actions))
```

For some reason code at `point #1` runs right after animation started. So it doesn't sequenced. Is it correct or I made mistake?

I know that I could use completion block for child node animation but I want to know is it possible with sequencing?

Comment: It looks like the issue only occurs with `runAction:onChildWithName`. If you run the sequence on the sprite directly (e.g., `sprite.runAction...`), it will work as expected.

Comment: Yes but I can't have sequence in this case. I need to start another actions only after sprite animation completes.

Comment: It should work if you return `action` (instead of `SKAction.runAction...`) from `animationAction` and then run `hero.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actions))`.

Answer (score 0):

First Question: It should be a sequence.

> A sequence is a set of actions that run consecutively. When a node runs a sequence, the actions are triggered in consecutive order. When one action completes, the next action starts immediately. When the last action in the sequence completes, the sequence action also completes.

That is what Apple documentation says. I had the same problem. For me works it with the completion block. I think its a swift bug, because it works great with objective-c

```
var actions = [SKAction]()
actions.append(hero.animationAction(Animation.Loose))
runAction(SKAction.sequence(actions), completion: {
    // point #1
})
```